# How to create mutiple instance of SSH and how to add specific users to specific instances?

Tags: ssh

I want to open multiple ports for SSH server and want to add some users to specific port only.

How I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need more `systemd` units (or init scripts for older systems) with different `sshd_config` (you can add this as `-f` option) and in these config files, you need to specify your blend of ports and users that are allowed to access this instance with options `AllowUsers`, `DenyUsers` or `AllowGroups` and `DenyGroups`